# Flutter GetX doesn't fires controller onInit method on duplicated page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using `GetX` in my project. I have a page `SearchProductPage`. I have a button on this page which opens same page, but with different parameters sent to the page.

```
Get.to(() => const SearchProductPage(), arguments: [
    {
      "newModel": 1,
      "brandType": 1,
      "xyz": 0,
      "pqr": 0,
      "label": "Product xyz"
    }
  ],
  preventDuplicates: true
);
```

And I have following codes in `onInit` method of the controller

```
@override
void onInit() async {
  super.onInit();

  var arguments = Get.arguments;

  if (arguments != null) {
      
      fromCategoryBlock.value = true;
      loadingFirstTime.value = true;
      searchResultLabel.value = arguments[0]["label"];

      await fetchSearchProducts(true).then((value) {
        loadingFirstTime.value = false;
      });
  }
}
```

`preventDuplicates` allows me to duplicate same page, but however, this time `onInit` is not fired.

I am new to `GetX`, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help any other suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what do you expect to happen in your sample of code

Comment: @Gwhyyy Firsttime, from `HomePage` if I go to `SearchProductPage`, everything works fine. On same very page (SearchProductPage) there is button, which upon clicking opens other instance of SearchPRoductPage as I have set `preventDuplicates` to true. THe page opens but onInit is not fired because there I want to catch arguments sent by button click.

Comment: did you injected dependency using Get.put(), right?

Comment: Yes its in `SearchProductPage`,

Answer (score 1):

using `Getx`, the `Get.put()` lets you inject an instance only once, then let you find that same instance with `Get.find()` from your multiple places:

```
Get.put(TextController()); // inject the instance
final controller1 = Get.find<TextController>(); // returns the same instance
final controller2 = Get.find<TextController>(); // returns also the same instance
```

This is what `Getx` is aiming to solve, However, for getting a whole new instance from everytime `Get.find()` is called, you should consider using `Get.create()`:

```
 Get.create(() => TextController()); // inject the instance
final controller1 = Get.find<TextController>(); // returns a new instance 
final controller2 = Get.find<TextController>(); // returns another new instance.
```

So everytime now you will call `Get.find()`, you will get separates instances of same controller, which means a new execute for lifecycle methods like `onInit()`, `onReady()`...

this now will cause that everytime you will push a new route with a dependency that was injected with `Get.create` you will get a new execute for it which solves your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, If I use `Get.create`, I cannot access obx variable like this `controller.myTestVariable.value`, if i do so i get error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

Comment: oh, there is another option that you have, which is not recommended but it should work, it's by calling forcibly the lifecycle methods like onInit() like a class member, controller.onInit()

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just use Get.off instead of Get.to. and no changes in controller injection. And this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: oh, good luck then!